# Creating Button Dynamically in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout, dynamically-generated

I'm new to Xamarin worked with android before and now I'm trying to make a board class but can't seem to create buttons dynamically.

I'm trying to generate buttons and for some reason right now I meet this problem while trying to dynamically make buttons...
hopefully you could help me :)

[image: My current problem]

in **activity**:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;

namespace App2
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

            Board board = new Board(this);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        }
    }
    class Board
    {
        RelativeLayout layout;
        Context context;
        const int length = 8;
        Button[,] buttons;


        public Board(Context context)
        {
            layout = (context as MainActivity).FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.root_layout);
            this.context = context;
            Init();
        }
        private void Init()
        {
            //Initializing the board
            buttons = new Button[length, length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    buttons[i, j] = new Button(context);
                    buttons[i, j].Text = (i + j).ToString();
                    buttons[i, j].SetX(50 * i);
                    buttons[i, j].SetY(20 * j);
                    layout.AddView(buttons[i, j]);

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

in **axml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: does it work now ?

Answer (score 2):

[image: My current problem]

in **activity**:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;

namespace App2
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

            Board board = new Board(this);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        }
    }
    class Board
    {
        RelativeLayout layout;
        Context context;
        const int length = 8;
        Button[,] buttons;


        public Board(Context context)
        {
            layout = (context as MainActivity).FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.root_layout);
            this.context = context;
            Init();
        }
        private void Init()
        {
            //Initializing the board
            buttons = new Button[length, length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    buttons[i, j] = new Button(context);
                    buttons[i, j].Text = (i + j).ToString();
                    buttons[i, j].SetX(50 * i);
                    buttons[i, j].SetY(20 * j);
                    layout.AddView(buttons[i, j]);

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

in **axml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ps**:i run it,it works,but buttons are overlapping and there may be problems in calculating the position of Buttons in your code.

Comment: Thank yo very much sir! have a nice day

Comment: Sure! I've just got in another problem.. when I run it , it tells me when: `layout.AddView(button[i,j]);` that the button is not an instance but I declared as a new button a few lines back

Comment: @EyalAbramovitch what's the problem ,have some error message ? I don't quite understand what you're describing, and `layout.AddView(buttons[i,j]);` spelling mistakes

Comment: when I run the app it isn't showing the buttons and takes me to the line where I add the view to the layout (`layout.AddView(buttons[i,j])`) telling me that the object is not defined and not an instance even though my program (theoretically) should do that for every button I make

Comment: could you update your code above and let me have a look

Comment: did you miss "this.context = context" in construct method

Comment: I've updated the code here It's exactly like mine but mine doesn't run :/

Comment: you move `Board board = new Board(this);` below `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_button);`Initialization must come after SetContentView